# How to insert arabic script into Tkinter text widget correctly?

Tags: python, tkinter, arabic, python-2.x

I have Arabic sentence/word which I'd like to insert into my Tkinter text widget.
However when I do insert the text I see the following result:

[image]

Here are the strings I am trying to insert: `'تاريخه' ,'تارِيخ'` First one was inserted correctly, the second one was extracted by findall() and garbled upon insertion.

Basically all my code (for the bold text on screenshot) is quite straighforward:

```
word = re.findall(u'word=.*', TEXT, re.UNICODE)[0] # searching for Arabic word and taking [0]
header = " ".join([QUERY, word]) # creating a varible to insert
text.insert('1.0', "".join([header,'\n'])) # inserting Arabic text
```

It looks like `re.findall()` function finds all occurrences of `'word=.*'` regexp in the TEXT and retrieves `word` variable in unicode notation.

I'm puzzled here.
**Can I somehow *convert* `word`  prior to insertion into the text widget?**

Comment: Can you copy that string here?

Comment: Are you on python 3 or python 2? If on Python 2, have you tried using Unicode strings (`u" ".join`) instead of plain ones (`" ".join`) for all relevant strings?

Comment: python2, but adding `u` does not solve the issue

Comment: Are you certain it is "garbled upon insertion", or could it be that `re.findall` is returning garbled results. If `re.findall` is returning an incorrectly encoded result, there's nothing tkinter can do about that.

Comment: What is printed if you put following two statement before the `re.findall...` line: `print repr(QUERY); print repr(TEXT)`

Comment: `print repr(QUERY)>>> u'\u0627\u0631\u062c\u0648'`

`print repr(TEXT)>>> 'word=\\u0631\\u064e\\u062c\\u0627'`

Comment: `TEXT` itself is escaped! (unlike QUERY).

Comment: Where does the `TEXT` come from? Do you process the string before doing regular expression matching?

Comment: I see, I am getting TEXT from another function that parses actual full text object. I guess I have to remove these backslashes then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you answered in the comment, the TEXT is already escaped. Change the function that generate the `TEXT` to correctly return a string.

If you can't control the function that generate the text, unescape the text using [`str.decode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.decode) with [`unicode_escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) encoding.

```
>>> TEXT = u'word=\\u0631\\u064e\\u062c\\u0627'
>>> print TEXT
word=\u0631\u064e\u062c\u0627
>>> TEXT = TEXT.decode('unicode-escape')
>>> print TEXT
word=رَجا
```

---

Example

```
# coding: utf-8

from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()

QUERY = u'\u0627\u0631\u062c\u0648'
TEXT = u'word=\\u0631\\u064e\\u062c\\u0627'  # escaped!!
TEXT = TEXT.decode('unicode-escape')
word = re.findall(u'word=.*', TEXT, re.UNICODE)[0]
header = " ".join([QUERY, word])
text.insert('1.0', "".join([header,'\n']))

root.mainloop()
```

[image]